# root folder and swapfile error in Filesystem Linux Mint 20.1

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am new to Linux mint 20.1 Ulyssa. I saw in File System under My Computer the root folder with the error symbol, and a swap file is unknown. I also see 2 unknown volumes under Devices, but i am not sure what they are, i do not have any external devices connected to my laptop. And i never saw these Devices before. I deleted some files from snap list today. Maybe it is the reason for that? Could anyone maybe help? Thank you in advance.

[image: root folder and swap file]
[image: unknown devices]
[image: un]

Answer (score 0):

This display is the `nemo` file manager, with a rather fancy theme.

**Important** if you don't want something that you installed, you can't just delete it. You should, at least in the early stages, be installing and removing packages - via the `synaptic` program. There are other program installation methods - but you don't need them for a fully functioning system.

You are looking at `/` and the red crosses indicate that you can't access `/root` (because that is root's home directory). Similarly, you have created a swap **file** which you cannot access directly. All of this is normal for a `/` folder.

I'm surprised to see a `snap` folder in the light of Mint's statement "Following the decision made by Canonical to replace parts of APT with Snap and have the Ubuntu Store install itself without users knowledge or consent, the Snap Store is forbidden to be installed by APT in Linux Mint 20."

Anyway, I'm going to guess that you have one disk of 500GB - its a Thinkpad-480? Which is nearly all used plus two tiny partitions of 54**MB** and 230**MB** which look like install attempts?? Note that they don't even add up to a measly 1GB.

If you haven't loaded any important user data, I'd recommend that you re-do a full disk (re)-install. Don't use Snap!

Comment: Can I recommend the Linux Mint Forum (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/) for Mint-specific problems?

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thank you for your answer. Yeah it is thinkpad 480 but with 256GB. I am not sure with these 2 partitions. I just wanted to delete them. Do you have any hint to get rid of these 2 partitions without re-doing a full disk ? Because i have already loaded some important data :( Yeah if the Linux Mint Forum helps :) Thank you

Comment: Run `gparted` to create/change/delete partitions. To delete a partition it must be first unmounted - which you can either do in gparted (usually) or via the command entry screen. Be very careful that you are choosing the correct partitions, in this case that is easy  because they are 54MB & 230MB. Once you have confirmed the deletion, any data in them can be considered to be deleted.

Comment: It is really weird, i opened `gparted`, after that is the 2 *devices* disappeared, i did not see them then in `gparted` window. But when i closed `gparted`, these 2 *devices* appear again. Do you have other hints to get rid of these *devices*?

Comment: `gparted` will only show partitions that actually exist - if you have software creating a "disk-like" device, then `gparted` won't see it. Although I know nothing about SNAP (except that Mint are strongly opposed to it - see the above answer for details). Have to say that the SNAP directory shouldn't be there - unless it was installed unknowingly or deliberately. Is it possible to re-install Mint from USB and check the layout immediately after the first boot in the new system?

Comment: I think i have to re-install Mint from USB :( it will take much time to backup the important data and reinstall distros :(